# How to set value at nouislider with an input in angular

Tags: angular, angular9

HTML

```html
<nouislider style="width: 90%;" 
            #slider 
            [config]="priceKeyboardConfig" 
            [(ngModel)]="pricesliderRange" 
            (mouseup)="applyFilter('','')"></nouislider>

<input class="form-control
       Filterinput" 
       style="font-size: 15px;" 
       placeholder="Min." 
       [(ngModel)]="pricesliderRange[0]">

<input class="form-control 
       Filterinput" 
       style="font-size: 15px;" 
       placeholder="Max." 
       [(ngModel)]="pricesliderRange[1]">
```

Angular Script

```ts
pricesliderRange: any = [0, 100000];
  priceKeyboardConfig: any = {
    connect: true,
    start: [0, 100000],
    step: 10,
    range: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100000,
    },
    behaviour: 'drag',
  }
```

ref image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtfUF.png